# Difference between @JsonIgnore and @JsonBackReference, @JsonManagedReference

Tags: java, json, jackson

I know both `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonManagedReference`, `@JsonBackReference` are used  to solve the `Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)`, what is the difference between these two?

**Note :**
These are Jackson annotations.

Comment: Yes I have tried out the documents and implemented it in the project but I was only confused with the technique they use in the process of conversion. As both of them produced the same result so I was confused where to prefer one over the other.

Comment: Three approaches to solve JSON recursive dependency: http://springquay.blogspot.com/2016/01/new-approach-to-solve-json-recursive.html

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Lets suppose we have

```
private class Player {
    public int id;
    public Info info;
}
private class Info {
    public int id;
    public Player parentPlayer;
}

// something like this:
Player player = new Player(1);
player.info = new Info(1, player);
```

---

### Serialization

`@JsonIgnore`

```
private class Info {
    public int id;
    @JsonIgnore
    public Player parentPlayer;
}
```

and `@JsonManagedReference` + `@JsonBackReference`

```
private class Player {
    public int id;
    @JsonManagedReference
    public Info info;
}

private class Info {
    public int id;
    @JsonBackReference
    public Player parentPlayer;
}
```

will produce same output. And **output** for demo case from above is: `{"id":1,"info":{"id":1}}`

### Deserialization

Here is main difference, because deserialization with `@JsonIgnore`
will just set null to the field so in our example parentPlayer will be == null.

[image]

But with `@JsonManagedReference` + `@JsonBackReference` we will get `Info` reference there

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot it cleared a lot of doubts in my mind. I was trying to search for this particular type of serialization which will not break or ignore either side of serialization

Comment: @varren I have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469722/how-to-make-pojo-and-parse-recursive-objects-using-jackson) where I need to parse recursive field and looks like maybe I need to use `@JsonManagedReference` but not sure how it's gonna work? I tried using `JsonManagedReference` and `JsonBackReference` but it seems doesn't work and everytime I get an exception so wanted to see if you can help me out.

Answer (score 50):

> are used to solve the Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

[`@JsonIgnore`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) is not designed to solve the *Infinite Recursion* problem, it just ignores the annotated property from being serialized or deserialized. But if there was a two-way linkage between fields, since `@JsonIgnore` ignores the annotated property, you may avoid the infinite recursion.

On the other hand, [`@JsonManagedReference`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html) and [`@JsonBackReference`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html) are designed to handle this two-way linkage between fields, one for *Parent* role, the other for *Child* role, respectively:

> For avoiding the problem,  linkage is handled such that the property
>   annotated with `@JsonManagedReference` annotation is handled normally
>   (serialized normally, no special handling for deserialization) and the
>   property annotated with `@JsonBackReference` annotation is not
>   serialized; and during deserialization, its value is set to instance
>   that has the "managed" (forward) link.

To recap, if you don't need those properties in the serialization or deserialization process, you can use `@JsonIgnore`. Otherwise, using the `@JsonManagedReference` /`@JsonBackReference` pair is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Ali this was helpful for me finding out the real difference between ignoring, serializing and de-serializing. Thanks a lot

Comment: @AliDehghani I have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469722/how-to-make-pojo-and-parse-recursive-objects-using-jackson) where I need to parse recursive field and looks like maybe I need to use `@JsonManagedReference` but not sure how it's gonna work? I tried using `JsonManagedReference` and `JsonBackReference` but it seems doesn't work and everytime I get an exception so wanted to see if you can help me out.