# @JsonIgnore vs @JsonBackReference in infinite recursive loop

Tags: java, json, loops, recursion, jackson

I'm wondering what is the main diffrence between those two annotations? Both are to fight with Infinite recursive loop problem. But in example

[Difference between @JsonIgnore and @JsonBackReference, @JsonManagedReference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392733/difference-between-jsonignore-and-jsonbackreference-jsonmanagedreference)

@varren showed usage of `@JsonBackReference` and I think that he created Infinite  recursive loop as well. Also when I try to use `@JsonBackReference`, it also creates a recursive loop in contrast to `@JsonIgnore`? So how can we manage the case of Infinite loop in order to use `@JsonBackReference`?

Comment: Look closely into what actual objects are in varren's answer: there is only single `Player` object (`Player@914`) and single `Info` object (`Info@915`). Please remove your answer from that question as well.

Comment: I deleted it, but your answer doesn't mean for me anything. Can you write it in diffrent words?

Comment: How else can I describe it? There's no infinite recursion because there is only a single instance of both `Player` and `Info` after deserializing `{id: 1, info: {id: 1}}`. If there was infinite recursion, that example would've produced it, giving error rather than those two objects. Q.E.D.

Comment: But what about the second image, below

**But with JsonManagedReference + JsonBackReference we will get Info referance there**?

It calls once PLayer once Info, once Player once Info, etc - doesn't it seems like an infinitive loop?

Comment: On second image, there is only **one** instance `Player@914` and only **one** instance `Info@915`. They both have references to each other, and debugger image displays that *if* you follow links blindly you will get into infinite recursion, **but we did not**, because of `@JsonManagedReference + @JsonBackReference` working.

Comment: Sometimes it's time to take things as they are.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

@M. Prokhorov
Ok, so what about mine case where I put those two annotations and get something like that:

[image]

Comment: check the delivered JSON from the reponse for syntax issues. I assume there's an error-message