# Jackson serializing of object omits the inversed side of @OneToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, jackson

I am using a Spring MVC Rest Controller to perform some simple CRUD operations on some entities. I'm am struggling a little with Jackson trying to figure out how to properly implement a @ManyToOne relationship. When Jacskon serializes the "inverse" side of the relationship, it omits the "owning" property. Heres a look at my code:

```
@Entity
public class Competition {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String name;

private String nameInUrl;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
@JsonBackReference(value="test")
private Sport sport;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getNameInUrl() {
    return nameInUrl;
}

public void setNameInUrl(String nameInUrl) {
    this.nameInUrl = nameInUrl;
}

public Sport getSport() {
    return sport;
}

public void setSport(Sport sport) {
    this.sport = sport;
}
}

@Entity
public class Sport {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String name;

private String nameInUrl;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="sport")
@JsonManagedReference(value="test")
private Set<Competition> competitions = new HashSet<Competition>();

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getNameInUrl() {
    return nameInUrl;
}

public void setNameInUrl(String nameInUrl) {
    this.nameInUrl = nameInUrl;
}

public Set<Competition> getCompetitions() {
    return competitions;
}

public void setCompetitions(Set<Competition> competitions) {
    this.competitions = competitions;
}
}
```

I would like to ask how I can achieve serializing the Competition entity in its entirety, without omitting the Sport entity?

Thanks, Dave

Comment: Did you try serialize this objects?

Comment: Yes, I did. The json representation of the objects deserialize as expected but when I serialize the competition object the sport property is omitted???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392733/difference-between-jsonignore-and-jsonbackreference-jsonmanagedreference/37394318) answer (if I understand right), `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` pair in serialization don't implies store whole object in json, just id. But when you deserialize this json you will obtain recursive connections without `StackOverFlow`. So it expected behavior (I think=)).

But if you need to pass in json whole objects, than you need to remove `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` and pass `@JsonIgnore` for `competitions` field in `Sport` class, but you will lost recursive connection in deserialize.

Also, you can try to write your own deserializer for `Sport` class for recursion obtain.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yea, it does seem like the expected behaviour of the Jackson  annotations. Just took me some time to figure that out.The solution I finally went with was to implement a custom deserializer. Works fine. Thanks for your help :)