# Spring Boot web cannot parse nested json to object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

first of all, i am quite new to spring (web mvc). I am building a RESTful service for my frontend. I am sending a JSON data but one object in that data was not parsed when it is received by spring.

Here is my data

**JSON Data**

```
{
    "comments" : []
    "description": "Testing",
    "images": "[\"path1\", \"path2\", \"path3\"]",
    "profile": {
        "id": 21234,
        "fullname": "John Michael Doe",
        "nickname": "Doe",
        "email": "jdoe@email.com",
        "profilePic": "/some/host/pic"
    }
}
```

**RequestMapper**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/wish")
public class WishlistController extends WishlistConverter{

        /* Some @Autowired here for services... */

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody RestWishlist input){
            try {
                logger.info("create({})",input);
                Wishlist wish = convert(input);
                wishlistService.create(wish);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error: {}",e.getMessage());
                return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }
}
```

**RestWishlist**

```
public class RestWishlist {

    private Long wishId;

    private List<RestComment> comments;

    private String description;

    private String images;

    private Long createdAt;

    private Long updatedAt;

    private RestProfile profile;

    /* Getters and Setters here */
}
```

**RestProfile**

```
public class RestProfile {

    private Long id;

    private String fullname;

    private String nickname;

    private String email;

    private String profilePic;
    /* Getters and Setters Here */
}
```

**RestComment**

```
public class RestComment {

    private Long commentId;

    private String description;

    private RestProfile profile;

    private Long createdAt;

    private Long updatedAt;
    /* Getters and Setters Here */
}
```

Now, i have a problem getting the "profile" part of my JSON data, log file show this

```
2017-12-03 20:50:31.740  INFO 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.s.s.web.controller.WishlistController  : create(RestWishlist [wishId=null, comments=[], description=Testing, images=["path1", "path2", "path3"], createAt=null, updatedAt=null])

2017-12-03 20:50:31.740  INFO 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.s.s.services.impl.WishlistServiceImpl  : create(Wishlist [wishId=null, comments=[], description=Testing, images=["path1", "path2", "path3"], createAt=null, updatedAt=null])
```

Comment: While sending data from service profile object is not received is it ?

Comment: If value of profile attribute is null then it might get skipped from the resulting JSON.

Comment: @swapnil - based from my JSON data i sent to spring, "profile" has value, please see my JSON data.

Comment: Try '@ModelAttribute' instead of '@RequestBody'.

Comment: tried using @ModelAttribute but all fields in my JSON data became null after spring received it.

Comment: I dsont see "profile" in controller log are you using @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) thats why ? because it should come as null at-least or Model is not in sync ?

To me it looks like either it is issue with Jackson conversion or ex: @JsonProperty("property_name") or your model is not in sync

Comment: Yep that is the problem, “profile” does not get parsed or converted from JSON data i sent.  I did not use any annotations for that. I just passed it as is from and received it as is. Please look at the wishlistcontroller log. That is the part when rest recieves the json data

Comment: Did you try @JsonManagedReference annotation? Ref - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392733/difference-between-jsonignore-and-jsonbackreference-jsonmanagedreference/37394318

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've found the problem after days of tracing. it's a simple bug and really, for me, careless.

"profile" was correctly set from json data. the reason why it does not appear in the logs is because the `toString()` method in `RestWishlist` class does not contain the profile. See below

**Before**

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RestWishlist [wishId=" + wishId + ", comments=" + comments + ", description=" + description
            + ", images=" + images + ", createdAt=" + createdAt + ", updatedAt=" + updatedAt + "]";
}
```

**After**

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RestWishlist [wishId=" + wishId + ", comments=" + comments + ", description=" + description
            + ", images=" + images + ", createdAt=" + createdAt + ", updatedAt=" + updatedAt + ", profile="
            + profile + "]";
}
```

I only added the profile variable to be displayed in `toString()` method

Comment: To parse nested JSON, did you not need to create a deserializer method to convert to Java POJO?