# got error after consuming rest service without @JsonIgnore

Tags: rest, spring-boot, angular6

I have this mapping     User *-----------1 Sexe

#### User.class

```java
public class User {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="sexe_id")
    private Sexe sexe;

   // Rest of the Attributes
}
```

#### Sexe.class

```java
public class Sexe {    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="sexe", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<User> users;

   // Rest of the Attributes

}
```

and the controller for rest call

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public List<User> getAllUsers()
{
     System.out.println("Get all Users...");
     List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
     userRepository.findAll().forEach(users::add);
     return users;
}
```

after using postman, I got this exception:

```
 at
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
 ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]    at
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
 ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]    at
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
 ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]    at
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
 ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]    at
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
 ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145)
 ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]    at
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107)
 ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]    at
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
 ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]    at
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
 ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]    at
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
 ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]    at
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
 ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]    at
```

After googling, I found that the solution is to use `@JsonIgnore`.
And this annotation resolves my problem. But the use of this annotation cause problems with angular.

Have you please any other proposition to avoid this exception ?. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: can you add the full stack trace,

Comment: Hello Sir @Avi, thanks for your reply. That's it the exception repeated many times, and stackoverflow can't support this repetition (alert: maximum number of characters)

Answer (score 0):

`JsonIgnore` is not the only solution. You can also use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`

```
@ManyToOne
@JsonBackReference
@JoinColumn(name="sexe_id")
private Sexe sexe;

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy="sexe", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<User> users;
```

See [Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693110/could-not-write-json-infinite-recursion-stackoverflowerror-nested-exception/47693766#47693766)