# Java JPA SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, one-to-many

I have table A and table B, table B have a fk that rererences to table A.

class EntityA

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableA")
public class EntityA {


... ... ...

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="entityA")
   private Set<EntityB> entityBList; 
    
}
```

class EntityB

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableB")
public class EntityB{


... ... ...

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="id_entityA", nullable=false)
   private EntityA entityA;
    
}
```

But when i try to call findAll method from repository (from EntityA) i get:

Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem using unidirectional relationship. Used this on my EntityA and erase the property entityA on EntityB.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_nfs")
private Set<EntityB> entityBList
```

The @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference annotations didnt fix my problem, probably i used wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is circular dependency issue you are facing.

Use  the @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference annotations to fix this issue.

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47715121/6572971 for how to use this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i put my solution.