# An issue with getting user roles in a Spring Rest application

Tags: java, spring, rest, roles

I have a RestController class with the following :

```
@RestController
public class UserRestController 
{
@Autowired
UserService userService;

@Autowired
private SecurityService securityService;

@Autowired
private UserValidator userValidator;

// Get a Single User
@GetMapping("/api/users/{id}")
public User getUserById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long userId) {
    return userService.getUserById(userId);
}
```

This is getUserById function in UserService :

```
 public User getUserById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long userId) {
    return userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User", "id", userId));
}
```

This is the result of a GET request on **localhost:8080/api/users/11** :

```
{
"id": 11,
"name": null,
"email": null,
"password": "$2a$10$HykDWcHU3vO9YAcdXiWieua9YyYMkwrNIk7WgpmVzVwENb71fDCsW",
"status": null,
"tel": null,
"confirmation": null,
"birth_date": null,
"createdAt": "2018-05-22T09:09:12.000+0000",
"updatedAt": "2018-05-22T09:09:12.000+0000",
"username": "ouissal@gmail.com"
}
```

This is the result of a GET request on **localhost:8080/users/11**

```
{
"name": null,
"email": null,
"password": "$2a$10$HykDWcHU3vO9YAcdXiWieua9YyYMkwrNIk7WgpmVzVwENb71fDCsW",
"status": null,
"tel": null,
"confirmation": null,
"birth_date": null,
"createdAt": "2018-05-22T09:09:12.000+0000",
"updatedAt": "2018-05-22T09:09:12.000+0000",
"username": "ouissal@gmail.com",
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/users/11"
    },
    "user": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/users/11"
    },
    "roles": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/users/11/roles"
    }
}
}
```

I do not have anything mapped for /users in my controller, how can I get the roles using my controller?

---

### edit

This is my User class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"}, 
    allowGetters = true)
```

public class User implements Serializable{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public User() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Id
@Column(name = "user_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "user_name")
//@NotBlank
private String name;

@Column(name = "user_email")
//@NotBlank
private String email;

@Column(name = "user_password")
@NotBlank
private String password;

@Column(name = "user_status")
private String status;

@Column(name = "user_tel")
private String tel;

@Column(name = "user_confirmation")
private String confirmation;

@Column(name = "user_birth_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date birth_date;

@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@CreatedDate
private Date createdAt;

@Column(nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@LastModifiedDate
private Date updatedAt;

@JsonBackReference
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;

@Column(name = "username")
@NotBlank
private String username;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getTel() {
    return tel;
}

public void setTel(String tel) {
    this.tel = tel;
}

public String getConfirmation() {
    return confirmation;
}

public void setConfirmation(String confirmation) {
    this.confirmation = confirmation;
}

public Date getBirth_date() {
    return birth_date;
}

public void setBirth_date(Date birth_date) {
    this.birth_date = birth_date;
}

public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public Date getUpdatedAt() {
    return updatedAt;
}

public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
}
```

and this is my role class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

@Id
@Column(name = "role_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "role_name")
private String name;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<User> users;



public Role() {
    super();
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried hitting `roles` url `http://localhost:8080/users/11/roles` are you getting roles there?

Comment: Yes I do get them, but what I don't understand is why do I get them although my controller isn't mapped for /users but for /api/users.
I don't know also in what way should I edit my controller to get them at /api/users/

Comment: Can you provide the code of the `User` class? You are directly returning it as your response, therefore it also has to have the roles included if you want to see them in your json response.

Comment: Are you using `spring-data-rest` lib? Looks like you are following this tutorial: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-intro

Comment: @Abaddon666 I have edited my question

Comment: have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37393711/2929488, i guess this this could explain why your roles are not serialized into json

Comment: @Abaddon666 Thank you! that has fixed my issue

Comment: You're welcome! I wrote a little answer for later visitors to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties annotated with `JsonBackReference` will not be included in your serialized content. 
To include the roles swap the `JsonBackReference` and `JsonManagedReference` annotations in `Role` and `User`.

This will include `Roles` into `User` but not the other way round.

For more information you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392733/difference-between-jsonignore-and-jsonbackreference-jsonmanagedreference/37393711#37393711)