# Spring boot one to many join Getting repeated json from DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

Product.java

```
@Entity @Table(name="product") public class Product {
          // ...
          @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="product_id")
          private Brand brand;
          // getters and setters
}
```

Brand.java

```
@Entity @Table(name="brand") public class Brand {
          // ....
          @OneToMany(mappedBy="brand", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
          private Set<Product> products;
}
```

BrandRepository.java

```
@Repository public interface BrandRepository extends JpaRepository<Brand, Long>{}
```

BrandController.java

```
@RestController @RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class BrandController {
          @Autowired private BrandRepository brandRepository;

          @GetMapping("/brands")
          public List<Brand> getAllBrands(){
                    return brandRepository.findAll();
          }
          @GetMapping("/brand/{id}")
          public ResponseEntity<Brand> getBrand(@PathVariable(value="id") Long bid) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
                    Brand brand = brandRepository.findById(bid).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("user not found"+bid));
                    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(brand);
          }
}
```

whenever i am trying to access /brands or /brand/1 , i am getting repeated json results like this:

for "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/brands"

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Apple","products":[{"id":4,"name":"Apple kndsksk ksjdsoijd sd","price":"2893787","brand":{"id":1,"name":"Apple","products":[{"id":4,"name":"Apple kndsksk ksjdsoijd sd","price":"2893787","brand":{"id":1,"name":"Apple","products":[{"id":4,"name":"Apple kndsksk ksjdsoijd sd","price":"2893787","brand":{"id":1,"name":"Apple","products":[{"id":4,"name":"Apple 
... and continues
```

for "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/brand/1"

```
{"id":1,"name":"Apple","products":[{"id":1,"name":"Apple kksf sfok sokoak","price":"9239932","brand":{"id":1,"name":"Apple","products":[{"id":1,"name":"Apple kksf sfok sokoak","price":"9239932","brand":{"id":1,"name":"Apple","products":[{"id":1,"name":"Apple kksf sfok sokoak","price":"9239932","brand":{"id":1,"name":"Apple","products":[{"id":1,"name":"Apple kksf sfok sokoak","price":"9239932","brand":{"id":1,"name":"Apple","products":[{"id":1,"name":"Apple kksf sfok sokoak","price":"9239932","brand":{"id":1,"name":"Apple","products":[{"id":1,"name":"Apple kks 
... and continues
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392733/difference-between-jsonignore-and-jsonbackreference-jsonmanagedreference).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @JsonIgnore annotation to suppress this infinite loop. For example:

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="product_id")
private Brand brand;
```